# How to remove magento default schema markup using google tag manager?

Tags: javascript, dom, magento, google-tag-manager

I am unable to remove default itemtypes and itemtypes from DOM page using google tag manager.
[image]

How to remove itemtype and itemscope from above body tag using javascript in google tag manager?

Comment: Hi pralayasimha Yedida. Have you checked my answer if this is working? Please feel free to upvote / accept if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Element.removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) method to remove your desired attributes from an element. In this case you can do something like this:

```
document.body.removeAttribute("itemtype");
document.body.removeAttribute("itemscope");
```

Comment: Above code not removing , still tags exist in body

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding this Custom HTML Tag in google tag manager:

```html
<script>
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

body.removeAttribute("itemtype");
body.removeAttribute("itemscope");
</script>
```